# WordPress checked function with in_array

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, checked, meta-boxes

Wordpress plugin.
I need to `checked="checked"` for checkboxes. I store them in an array.

The problem I'm having is that if the checkboxes are stored they don't "check" the checkbox.

```
 public function display() {

    $html = '';
    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'nonce_check_value' );
    $html .= '<label for="CMBUserBoxName">Name metabox: </label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="CMBUserBoxName" value="' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'CMBUserBoxName', true ). '">';
    $data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'CMBUserRequestedOption');
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';

    $html .= 'Radio: ';
    $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="CMBUserRequestedOption[Radio]" value="1" '.checked( in_array( 1, $data ), 1, false ).' />';



    $html .= '</br>';

    $html .= 'Checkbox: ';
    $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="CMBUserRequestedOption[Checkbox]" value="1" '.checked( in_array( 1, $data ), 1, false ).' />';


    echo $html;
}
```

`print_r($data)` =

```
Array
(
    [0] => a:2:{s:5:"Radio";s:1:"1";s:8:"Checkbox";s:1:"1";}
)
```

The save function:

```
if(isset($_POST['CMBUserRequestedOption'])  ){
      $data=serialize($_POST['CMBUserRequestedOption']);

      update_post_meta($post_id, 'CMBUserRequestedOption', $data);
```

I think the `checked()` is missing something.
`checked( in_array( 1, $data ), 1, false )`

Comment: What is your `print_r($data);` data?

Comment: Please see updated

Comment: is it array `a:2:{s:5:"Radio";s:1:"1";s:8:"Checkbox";s:1:"1";}` ?

Comment: Yeah it is. So what am I missing?

Comment: No that is not an array... try to change your get post meta like this `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'CMBUserRequestedOption', true)`

Comment: Please do explain why not? It's serialised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$data` contains a [*serialized*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) string (at index `0`). If you want to check the data it contains, you have to unserialize it.

```
$data = Array(
    'a:2:{s:5:"Radio";s:1:"1";s:8:"Checkbox";s:1:"1";}'
);
$data[0] = unserialize($data[0]);
```

Then you could use `checked($data[0]['Radio'], 1, false)`:

```
$html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="CMBUserRequestedOption[Radio]" value="1" '.checked($data[0]['Radio'], 1, false).' />';
$html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="CMBUserRequestedOption[Checkbox]" value="1" '.checked($data[0]['Checkbox'], 1, false).' />';
```

Or as pointed out by @Nawin, you can get the data in a value, instead of array:

```
$data  = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'CMBUserRequestedOption', true);
$data = unserialize($data);
// echo checked($data['Radio'], 1, false);
// echo checked($data['Checkbox'], 1, false);

$html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="CMBUserRequestedOption[Radio]" value="1" '.checked($data['Radio'], 1, false).' />';
$html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="CMBUserRequestedOption[Checkbox]" value="1" '.checked($data['Checkbox'], 1, false).' />';
```

See also [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize).

Comment: Thank you for explaining. If I check nothing and save the value in the database isn't updated. So for some reason it always needs one option checked?

Comment: @Interactive I'm really sorry, but I don't know how Wordpress works, and how it saves posted values in the database.

Comment: Allright. Maybe another question. helped me a lot tho'. Thumbs up!